# Excel Percentage increase greater than or equal to

Tags: excel

I'm having a problem with an excel formula not working. In cell F8 I used the following formula.

```
=IF(F9>=14%, "Yes", "No")
```

As shown in the image below, F9 equals 14%, but for some reason it's displaying "No" when it should say "Yes".

The formula I used in F9 is.... `=(F4-F7)/F7`

I'm sure it's something really simple/stupid that I'm overlooking but I can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

Comment: It may be precision error. Use another cell to show `F9-0.14`

Comment: Use: `=IF(ROUND(F9,2)>=14%,"Yes","No")`

Comment: This worked!!!!   =IF(ROUND(F9,2)>=14%,"Yes","No")
You guys are life savers and much appreciated.